# Deploying a package for SSIS on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have been reading up on SSIS but I have never used it before. One thing I am slightly confused on; if an SSIS project is deployed on a server, is there a way to make changes to it without recompiling the project? In SQL 2016 and versions before SQL 2012 I have read that you can deploy a single package, but it seems like you still have to recompile the project. Is this correct? There is no way to 'make changes on the fly'?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a programming question so much as a 'how does this technology work' question.  What do you mean by recompile?  Is this a package deployment model or a project deployment model?

Comment: Package deployment model. When I say recompile I mean, can I add changes to the existing deployed packages without having to rebuild anything?

Comment: If you are asking if it is possible to make changes to the package on the server without opening Visual Studio, then the answer is no.  SSIS heavily relies on metadata.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question then.. if I wanted to make a minor change to one package that is currently deployed on the server, can I deploy that one package, the old package will be replaced with the new package, and nothing else in the project needs to be rebuilt?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, as long as you have the correct permission on the Integration Services instance.  You can right click the package to be updated and select 'Upgrade Packages'

Comment: This is from the MSDN: If you update only a few packages in the project, you may not want to redeploy the entire project. To deploy only a few packages, you can create a new Integration Services project, add the updated packages to the new project, and then build and deploy the project. Package configurations are automatically copied with the package when you add the package to a different project.                                                       It sounds to me like you have to redeploy the project if you update any packages, is this incorrect?

Comment: Could you link that article?  That might be referring to project deployment

Answer (score 0):

yes, these answers are correct! You can not make changes on any package without using Visual Studio.

There is one solution If you don't want to change the existing project. SSMS provide you permission to export the project ISPAC file. you can open that file in VS and can make changes into a new project. finally, you can re deploy it again.